# Append a string conditionally to commit-msg using hooks

Tags: git, shell, sed, hook, pre-commit-hook

How could we write a `commit-msg` hook, for appending a string `[XYZ]` to all commits, except when the original commit message has `[exclude-XYZ]` in it somewhere?

I am a beginner with shell scripting and here is what I have tried unsuccessfully so far:

```
if echo "$1" | grep "[exclude-XYZ]"
then 
else echo "$1 [XYZ]" >> "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're echoing the filename, rather than checking its contents. Try something like:

```
if fgrep '[exclude-XYZ]' -- "$1" >/dev/null; then 
  :
else
  echo "[XYZ]" >> "$1"
fi
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
fgrep '[exclude-XYZ]' -- "$1" >/dev/null || echo '[XYZ]' >> "$1"
```